# Разбить программно таблицу на 2 подтаблицы

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. На вход поступает часть HTML кода. В нём может быть одна или несколько таблиц. Необходимо каждую таблицу разбить на 2 подтаблицы и поместить внутрь таблицы с 2-х ячеек - в левую ячейку первую часть, соответственно в правую - вторую часть. Таблицы обычно 2-х колоночные, но могут быть и с объединёнными по горизонтали ячейками (если сложно, то можно это не учитывать).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите как проще программно это сделать. Возможно есть готовые сниппеты.
Задача решается на php. Я так понимаю, что скорее всего для этого нужно использовать HTML парсеры, типа Simple HTML DOM, но возможно есть решение без использования сторонних библиотек.

Это необходимо для программного формирования pdf на лету, может быть использовано для email рассылок и в других задачах, где используется html4.

Comment: Вам сюда https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

Comment: @Bykuznec - возможно вы не правильно поняли - таблицы на сайте отображаются нормально, но при автоматическом формировании pdf для экономии места, их необходимо разбить на 2 части и вывести рядом...

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074174/Simple-Way-to-Convert-HTML-Table-Data-into-PHP-Arr вот пример как из html string таблицы получить массив. Остается только из массива собрать 2 таблицы обратно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, мы знаем, что на вход приходит HTML, там есть одна или несколько таблиц, и их нужно разделить на два куска, которые надо сложить в две колонки, тоже таблицей

Подзадачи:

1. Выделение блока таблицы. Считаем, что таблицы не вложены друг в друга, хотя это можно тоже проверить отдельно. Если таблицы вложены, то разбить нормальные при данной постановке задачи мы не сможем, нужны дополнительные условия.
2. В выделенном блоке таблицы нужно выбрать все строки. Ячейки могут быть произвольно объединены по горизонтали, нам без разницы, мы работаем со строками таблицы целиком.
3. Полученные на 2 шаге строки нужно поделить пополам и сложить в две дополнительные таблицы - одна слева, другая справа.

```html
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('input1.html');

// Смотрим, что было в начале
print $html->save();

// Ищем таблицы
$tables = $html->find('table');
if ($tables && is_array($tables) && count($tables)) {
 foreach ($tables as $table) {
  // Разбиваем исходную таблицу на две части
  $left_table = new simple_html_dom();
  $left_table->load($table->outertext);
  $right_table = new simple_html_dom();
  $right_table->load($table->outertext);
  // Из первой таблицы необходимо удалить все строки с номером более count/2
  $rows = $left_table->find('tr');
  if ($rows && is_array($rows) && ($count = count($rows))) {
   foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
    if ($index >= round($count/2)) {
     $row->outertext = '';
    }
   }
  }
  // Из второй таблицы необходимо удалить все строки с номером менее count/2
  $rows = $right_table->find('tr');
  if ($rows && is_array($rows) && ($count = count($rows))) {
   foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
    if ($index < round($count/2)) {
     $row->outertext = '';
    }
   }
  }
  // Собираем результат. Здесь можно поправить внешний вид результата так, как нужно
  $two_tables = '
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top">'.$left_table->outertext.'</td>
   <td valign="top">'.$right_table->outertext.'</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  ';
  // Заменяем исходную таблицу на две
  $table->outertext = $two_tables;
  // Освобождаем память, может понадобиться при большом количестве таблиц, но в целом не обязательно
  $left_table->clear();
  $right_table->clear();
 }
}

// Выводим результат после замены, в виде строки
print $html->save();

// Также можно сохранить в файл
$html->save('output.html');

?>
```

> Код PHP не хочет вставляться как код, форматирование тупит, поэтому
>   вставляю через сниппет. Прошу прощения за причиненные неудобства,
>   выполнять его не надо

За тестовые данные я взял простую таблицу из ссылки в комментариях к вопросу:

[image: Входная таблица]

Результатом работы разбиения будет вот такая таблица с двумя таблицами:

[image: Выходная таблица]